# How to set My Application instead of default android contacts's Application

Tags: android, default, contacts

when I click on contact icon in menu list then open my application instead of in built andriod.

just tell me what i do in menifest...

Plz help me n thanks in advance.

Plz give me your gold time for it..

Answer (score 0):

If we look in the AndroidManifest of the internal Contacts.apk in Android we find this

```
<activity .....>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/person" android:host="contacts"/>
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" android:host="com.android.contacts"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Which is the intent filter that they use inside the activity they want to show when someone Views a Contact. You may have to do a little messing around to get the exact right effect that you want, but as far as I can understand your question, that is the answer that you need.