# How can we replace out of the box contact application with Own app

Tags: android, contacts

I am developing a Contacts Application for Android. Now how can I replace Default out of the box Contacts Application with my new application?

Comment: Please don't just grab every single tag (use ones that actually have meaning to your question - "custom" and "replace" are meaningless, yet you used them), and don't put tag information in the subject line of your question. Tags are just that - ways to tell people what your question is about, and to group questions by topic. Adding it in the subject just clutters it with noise that makes it harder for people to see what you're actually asking. Thanks. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set My Application instead of default android contacts's Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457799/how-to-set-my-application-instead-of-default-android-contactss-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace an Android system application (meaning one bundled with the device when shipped) with one of your own unless you are creating a custom ROM image...period.

You may, however, emulate that application's functionality so that anytime a user would be presented with an option to jump into the default Contacts app, they can choose yours instead.  You do this by exposing that your application responds to the same list of Intents as that particular app.  [Here is a link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) to the current Contacts manifest to give you an idea of which Intents it responds to.

The user will be presented with an option to select your app as the default when triggering a Contacts related action.  **IF THE USER CHOOSES** to make your application the default handler of these activities, they may do so, but there is not way to force that decision upon them.

HTH